# Resources exceeded during query execution when I use join each

Tags: google-bigquery

I tried running a join query on Bigquery and I got the "table too large for joining" error which I understand. Then I tried using JOIN EACH instead of JOIN and I got an error saying "Resources exceeded during query execution". Are there limits on JOIN EACH that I need to be aware of too?

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing a `GROUP BY` or a `COUNT DISTINCT` with a large bucket count, you can get resources exceeded when doing a `JOIN EACH` query (each of these has workarounds).

If you share your query, we can give a more precise diagnosis.

Comment: Thanks Jordan. The table on the left hand side of my join is a union of multiple tables. If I keep the union under 10 tables, it works fine, otherwise I get the above mentioned error. I worked around it by  running the query multiple times by breaking up the left side of the join to have less than 10 tables.

Comment: If you share more about the query you're running, we may be able to help figure out how to get the query to run with all of your tables so you don't have to break it up into multiple queries.